# Leaflet timer. Highlighting a different town (polygon) every secs

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I have a map with 4 towns using Leaflet. Mouseover and Mouseout work fine but I would like to have a timer that automatically focus on each town in rotation every 5 or 10 secs. I was trying to find in the documentation a way to find all polygons on the map and then loop indefinitely into these but I can't access them individually to apply functions to highlight and reset styles.

```
$.getJSON('./data/mymap.json', function (geojson) {
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(geojson, {
    style: function () {
        return {
            color: 'blue'
        }
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on('mouseover', function () {
            this.setStyle({
                color: 'green'
            });
            document.getElementById("mapdetails").innerText = layer.feature.properties.name;
        });
        layer.on('mouseout', function () {
            geojsonLayer.resetStyle(this);
            document.getElementById("mapdetails").innerText = '';
        });
        layer.on('click', function () {
            mymap.fitBounds(arrayBounds);
        });
    }
}).addTo(mymap);

});

function highlightLayer(layerID) {
    mymap._layers['name'+layerID].setStyle(highlight); }

var highlight = {
    'color': '#333333',
    'weight': 2,
    'opacity': 1 };

$(document).ready(function() {

    var layerGroup = L.LayerGroup([polygon]);

    for (var i in this._layers) {
        if (this._layers[i].options.name == 'Mytown') {
            console.log('found');
        }
    }
```

Comment: `layerGroup.eachLayer()` should help - https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layergroup-eachlayer

Comment: @peeebeee Yeah I looked into this but I cannot find the features inside this large object when I print to console.     

mymap.eachLayer(function(layer){
        console.log(layer)
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call eachLayer() or getLayers() from the geojsonLayer.

```
var i = 0;
function highlightLayer(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      geojsonLayer.resetStyle(); //To clear style of all layers
      var layers =  geojsonLayer.getLayers();
      if(layers.length >= i){
         i = 0;
      }
      layers[i].setStyle(highlight);
      i++;
      highlightLayer(); //Restart Timer
   },1000);
}
```